# i18n for Facebook Fanpage Tab

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know of a way to display the name of a tab in the language the user has her/his Facebook set to? For example, if s/he uses Facebook in Korean, is there a way for my app's tab name to be displayed in Korean instead of English? (Similar to how the Facebook core tabs are localized.)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your app by going to facebook.com/developers, clicking your fan page tab from the far left list of apps, click edit in the upper right on the settings bar, choose "translate your app" under related links, click the language you want to translate it in, and then you should see your current fan page tab name and you can type in a translated value.

Comment: Yes, i found this option but the app name didn't change as I change the language of my FB account. The translation has been published already. Does it work automatically or I need to give a special variable/id to the Tab Name Field?

Comment: Does this still work? I can't find a way to localize the page tab name in the current version of FB developer console.