# How to localize FB page tab name?

Tags: facebook, localization

I'd like to translate the page tab name of our FB app. But it seems that this isn't possible with the build in [localization tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization). The [page tab documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs) doesn't mention localization either.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728107/i18n-for-facebook-fanpage-tab) seems to be related but the answer doesn't work anymore.

How do I localize the page tab name?

Comment: You mean for the same page, depending on the visitor’s locale – or for different pages that embed your app and are in different languages?

Comment: Both. The app is embedded on multiple pages. And depending on the locale of the visitor the tab name should change like the other facebook tab names.